# Get unique features for each set in a collection of sets

Tags: python, set

I'm struggling to search how to do this; maybe there's a word for this set operation I'm not aware of.

I have several sets with overlapping elements, and I'd like to find which elements are unique to each given set. For example:

```py
sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}
```

I can see that ***f*** is unique to ***cats*** and ***c*** is unique to ***rats***. So I'd like to do some set operations or something to yield that data:

```py
uniq = {
    'rat': {'c'},
    'cat': {'f'},
    'dog': set(),
}
```

*(Bonus question, mainly out of curiosity-- instead of sets, if I put these in a pandas / numpy 2d matrix, is there a neat way to do this same operation? e.g. where 'rat', 'cat', 'dog' was columns and a,b,c,... was rows or vice versa)*

Comment: Do you want a new data structure or modify the existing one or are both ok?

Comment: @KellyBundy Either is fine!

Answer (score 4):

Get the difference of each set with all the other sets.

```
sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

uniques = {k: v.difference(*(v1 for k1, v1 in sets.items() if k1 != k)) 
           for k, v in sets.items()}

print(uniques) # {'rat': {'c'}, 'cat': {'f'}, 'dog': set()}
```

Answer (score 3):

This one takes time proportional to the total number of elements, regardless of how many sets there are.

```py
from collections import Counter

sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

ctr = Counter()
for s in sets.values():
    ctr.update(s)
uniq = {
    k: {x for x in v if ctr[x] == 1}
    for k, v in sets.items()
}

print(uniq)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBCsIwEEVxmyO4ml1aqAV3InTlMcRFTRMNtklNJlKRnsRNN3ooT2NGqwhm8ReZN38-_3pvz7i3ZhhuAdVs8ZhMlbMNCFvXUqC2xoNuWusQVjYYlI4xL9FDARcG8XFXIl_ChZc8A74lESQV77M3IP6AikR9gcrufoH43TMm0MUb480kZco6iFEM0PX8VNZB-iRdvhwim4e2KlEmPmUsGH385jtE5w5ou6PtE2hF_LrbQFHAvH9BND5kNBz9Ncom2lOQ1mmDCXmm74rGpj6NPQE)

---

A perhaps faster version:

```py
from collections import Counter

sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

ctr = Counter()
for s in sets.values():
    ctr.update(s)
dupe = set(ctr - Counter(set(ctr)))
uniq = {k: v - dupe for k, v in sets.items()}

print(uniq)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBCsIwEEVxm0PI7JJA61oKrjxJTVINtklMJoJIT-LGjR7K0zjRKoJZDGR48__Mv9zDCXfeXa-3jF29fMzmXfQDKN_3RqH1LoEdgo8Ia58dmshYMphgBWcG9HhskTdw5i2vgG9KUaVoPlZvQP0BupTuC2i__QWoPTKmMJLH5Ckk63wEWsVBcV8c2z6bJGTzUiB2kYNu0Ygkmc7B0ChxoojUX5GpI6Vk2dlDOWHfwJGI10hx2Ff0_5hYNAN50DIhWoeiDMl3TFNan9Se)

---

And a version modifying the existing collection:

```py
from collections import Counter

sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

ctr = Counter()
for s in sets.values():
    ctr.update(s)
dupe = set(ctr - Counter(set(ctr)))
for s in sets.values():
    s -= dupe

print(sets)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZBBCsIwEEVxOwdwPbs00HYtBVeepCapFtokJBNBSk_iphs9lKcxsbUIgrP4i-HN_8O_PeyVzkZP0z1QU-yem23jTI_CdJ0S1Brtse2tcYQHEzQpB-AVedzjABiHuZpYhQOrWY7smEQkkWzMZ0D8ADJJswLSnL6BuB4BBLmYsWRmHBrjML6iMaWXl7oLyme8ejtEtgxW1qQyz0EGq-Jp5LJkUqwmy4bz_24eiz0mEwDrWk3pzvO5nqWlT1sv)

Comment: Neat, this works, thank you! I might end up accepting @barmar's answer though, since it's a little simpler using just set operations. :)

Comment: @catleeball Sure, whatever you like best. Barmar's of course is inefficient with larger data sets, while mine has optimal complexity.

Comment: oh word? I'm going to finish my current work and circle back to this to think-- I was initially under the impression both would amortize to O(n) runtime and I assumed the set operations would have some neat underlying C implementation. Then again, the unions would repeat set comparisons more and-- oh yeah, I think yours is a bit more runtime optimal! I was planning to run performance tests on the different solutions (including the pandas table solution) tomorrow morning likely and will post here. :)

Comment: @catleeball Are you talking about your answer's version, with exactly three sets? That's linear time as well, yes. I assumed you might also have cases with more than just three sets, i.e., a more general case like also handled by Barmar's answer. That's slower than linear with a larger number of sets. Looking forward to your performance tests.

Comment: Late to the party. As I was first reading the answers in the order of scores I was thinking to myself, "how can such an inefficient solution receive the highest score?" And then I scrolled down...

Comment: @blhsing People love oneliners? :-) Also, if there are very few sets (like only three), then it's probably fast.

Answer (score 1):

Using set comprehension (edited after comment from Kelly Bundy):

```py
unique = {}
for current_key, current_value in sets.items():
    values_in_other_sets = { item for key, value in sets.items() for item in value if (key != current_key) }
    unique[current_key] = current_value - values_in_other_sets

print(unique)
```

Result:

```py
{'rat': {'c'}, 'cat': {'f'}, 'dog': set()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) version:

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```py
sets = {
    "rat": {"a", "b", "c", "d"},
    "cat": {"a", "b", "d", "f"},
    "dog": {"a", "b"},
}

df = (
    pd.concat(
        [pd.Series([1] * len(v), index=v, name=k) for k, v in sets.items()], axis=1
    )
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   rat  cat  dog
d    1    1    0
a    1    1    1
b    1    1    1
c    1    0    0
f    0    1    0
```

---

Then you can do:

```py
uniq = df[df.sum(axis=1) == 1]
for c in uniq.columns:
    print(c, (uniq[uniq[c] != 0]).index.values)
```

Prints:

```
rat ['c']
cat ['f']
dog []
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting, thank you! :)  Tomorrow morning after my current work is through, I might run performance tests between all the solutions; I'm curious how the pandas table version will compare!

Comment: @catleeball If you don't have pandas dataframe created like that beforehand I bet pure python solution with sets/`Counter` will be faster (creating dataframe from the sets takes time). But all depends on your data.

Answer (score 1):

just another approach, instead of going through set and then comparing and subtracting (set difference). map each value of key to key itself ie 'a' key map to `rats` value  and then iterate through this mapper and find out the key with only one value and make final result from it

```
>>> sets
{'rat': {'d', 'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'cat': {'d', 'a', 'f', 'b'}, 'dog': {'a', 'b'}}
>>> mapper = {}
>>> for k, v in sets.items():
...     for j in v:
...             if j not in mapper:
...                     mapper[j] = [k]
...             else:
...                     mapper[j].append(k)
...
>>> mapper
{'d': ['rat', 'cat'], 'a': ['rat', 'cat', 'dog'], 'b': ['rat', 'cat', 'dog'], 'c': ['rat'], 'f': ['cat']}

>>> uniq = {k:set() for k in sets.keys()}
>>> uniq
{'rat': set(), 'cat': set(), 'dog': set()}
>>>
>>> for k, v in mapper.items():
...     if len(v) == 1:
...             if v[0] in sets:
...                     uniq[v[0]].add(k)
...
>>> uniq
{'rat': {'c'}, 'cat': {'f'}, 'dog': set()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use try the code below

```
from functools import reduce

{el[0]: el[1].difference(reduce(set.union,[v[1] for v in sets.items() if v != el])) for el in sets.items()}
```

or without `reduce`

```
{el[0]: el[1].difference(set.union(*[v[1] for v in sets.items() if v != el])) for el in sets.items()}
```

which returns

```
{'rat': {'c'}, 'cat': {'f'}, 'dog': set()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one modifies the existing collection. My dictionary `d` maps values like the `'a'` to the first set containing it. Go through the sets. If a value in the current set was already contained in an earlier set, remove it from both. Otherwise, remember the current set as the first one containing the value.

```py
sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

d = {}
for s in sets.values():
    for x in list(s):
        if x in d:
            s.remove(x)
            d[x].discard(x)
        else:
            d[x] = s

print(sets)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVBBDoIwEIzXnnxCb4UEORsSX2I8VLbVJkhJtxAM4SVeuOijfI1dQcUwhznMzGY2c3tUV3-25TDca6832-dqjcoj3_GO8QDhpBcZ74QUCRdHopwIRJ-MgXwRACL9DYA9zQNB7hkDauiZto4jNyWn0rSRRa0wirP3IXkteYVBH-GkEoweDfhJBEyduthGRW38p8O-PaRgMJcO5p4qUGWLZHgMGaucKUNp-Coeh5n2-ez0Ag)

---

Another, first finding which elements occur two (or more) times, then removing those.

```py
sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

one = set()
two = set()
for s in sets.values():
    two |= one & s
    one |= s
for s in sets.values():
    s -= two

print(sets)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3nxWnlhQr2CpUcykAgXpRYom6lUK1eqK6joJ6EohIBhEp6rU6EAXJGApSQEQaXEFKfjqyAqBwLRdXfl4q0A6gVRqaXCXl-XB2Wn6RQrFCZh6IW6xXlphTmlqsoWkFNgmkrsZWAaRVTaEYLARiA4WK8eorVtC1BWnm4iooyswr0QAp0YT4FuppmOcB)

Comment: Very clever indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using @barmar 's comment using the union method and the subtraction operator:

```py
rat = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
cat = {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'}
dog = {'a', 'b'}

rat - cat.union(dog)
>>> {'c'}

dog - rat.union(cat)
>>> set()

cat - rat.union(dog)
>>> {'f'}
```

Comment: Alternatives: `rat - (cat | dog)` and `rat - cat - dog`.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way (but probably not the ideal) it would be first to create a list with all elements of the set that are single and you want them to be kept. And then by using a for loop you could go through all "categories" and create a new set with all the single elements that are not in the other categories at all.

```
sets = {
    'rat': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
    'cat': {'a', 'b', 'd', 'f'},
    'dog': {'a', 'b'},
}

all_elem = []
for i in sets.keys():
    temp_elements = list(sets[i])
    all_elem = all_elem + temp_elements 
    
single_vals = set([x for x in all_elem if all_elem.count(x) == 1])

final_dict = {}
temp_list = []
for i in sets.keys():
    for j in single_vals:
        if j in list(sets[i]):
            temp_list.append(j)
    final_dict[i] = temp_list
    temp_list = []
print(final_dict)
```

The out come of the following it is a dictionary with the categories of the initial set with the single elements: `{'rat': ['c'], 'cat': ['f'], 'dog': []}`